# RequestTracker - how to allow users to create their own login or self-register?

Tags: user-accounts, request-tracker

I recently set up a new RequestTracker 4 install, and am trying to figure out how I can allow users to self-register.     This is a private / LAN based system, and currently when you access the URL, you see the request tracker login screen.    Is there some way to enable a simple registration option, so people can enter their email and/or username to register a new account?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a private system, your best bet might be to use [RT::Extension::LDAPImport](https://metacpan.org/module/RT::Extension::LDAPImport) to import user accounts from LDAP/AD (assuming you have a system like that). Then you can set up [RT::Authen::ExternalAuth](https://metacpan.org/module/RT::Authen::ExternalAuth) to allow users to use their LDAP password.

If you want to stick with RT accounts, you can set up RT to create new accounts from email submissions if the email sender doesn't yet have an RT account. You could then use a template like [this one](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/AutogeneratedPassword) from the RT user wiki. There isn't a standard feature to do this from the web UI, but you could use the code from that template to add a "Create Account" page.

In either case, you'll want to think about what permissions and status to give the new auto-generated user accounts (Privileged or not, etc.). Unprivileged users will see the self-service pages by default and you need to give them permission to see tickets and the queues(s) you want to give them access to.